# MIPS program that computes an output

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to know how write a **MIPS** program that executes a math expression where `a`, `b`, `c` are user provided integer inputs, and `s` is computed and printed as an output.

```
s = (a + b) - (c + 101)
```

I just started learning MIPS.

Comment: To get user input or to output a result, google "mips syscall".  Then try to make a [mre] and come back if you have some specific problems.

Comment: compile it and examine the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to act like a compiler: decompose the given expression into smaller parts that the hardware can execute.

We can start this decomposition in C, to get a better idea of what we need to do.  Like in assembly language, when we decompose, we make simpler statements, *interconnected by temporary variables*.

```
s = (a + b) - (c + 101)
```

Let's do this transformation in C then, introducing temporary variables to connect the simplified parts.

```
t1 = a + b
t2 = c + 101
s = t1 - t2
```

This form has a name, [Three Address Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code).

The MIPS translation of this is pretty straightforward: As the assembly language programmer, we choose a CPU register to the temporary variables, so `t1` from the above C code, might go `$t1` MIPS register, `t2` to `$t2`.  (Here we observe that the values for `t1` and `t2` are both needed simultaneously: that is, their lifetimes *overlap*.  Thus, they each need their own assembly location, i.e. their own CPU register.)

We also need to know where `a`, `b`, and `c` are located.  Let's assume they are parameters in MIPS designated argument CPU registers `$a0`, `$a1`, and `$a2` respectively.

This means that the first line `t1 = a + b`, can translate into a MIPS instruction:

```
add $t1, $a0, $a1
```

and so on:

```
addi $t2, $a2, 101    # here we use an "add immediate" since one operand is a constant
```

and finally, assuming we want `s` in MIPS CPU register `$s1`:

```
sub $s1, $t1, $t2
```

---

The general idea is that in assembly language / machine code, we cannot do everything we want in a single instruction, so we have to break the code down into smaller pieces and use multiple instructions.

We have to understand more detail about locations of variables, and management of temporary values, since the CPU registers are limited to a small number (whereas in C we can have virtually unlimited variables as needed (i.e. for Three Address Coding), and also of course, C can forgo TAC: use parenthesis and operator precedence to hold intermediate values without even naming a temporary variable.).  (If we run out of CPU registers in assembly, we have to write code to shuffle values between memory and registers, using memory to hold any overruns.)

Management of registers — for long-live variables & for short-lived temporaries — is a big part of the job of writing assembly language.  Two variables that have overlapping lifetimes cannot share the same CPU register, yet since the CPU registers are finite, we can run out for larger expressions.  On MIPS, there are 10 registers specifically dedicated as temporaries (though there are some other registers, too).  We need to know when we are finished with a temporary value, since then its CPU register can be repurposed for something else.